# Javascript force changing appear before page fully loaded

Tags: javascript, browser, synchronization

I write a website modeled by Javascript. In the web page I wrote a message to prevent user to activate JS. In my JS code I remove this node at first step. The problem is that the effect appear until the page is fully loaded...

```
var modelerBody = null;

var loadingNode = document.createElement("div");

loadingNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageGeneric['loading']));
loadingNode.setAttribute("id", "loading");

window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("jsDisabled").remove()

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.insertBefore(loadingNode, body.childNodes[0]);
    inflateForms();
    modelerBody = new Modeler.Screen(body.childNodes[1]);
    modelerBody.modelize();
    // Remove Loading message
    body.childNodes[0].remove();

}
```

How I can solve this problem ?
Sorry for my English I am learning it...

Comment: You might want to look at the [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag.  It's designed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Javascript before the element has loaded by putting the script tag above the div you want to delete, but it won't be able to find the div because it hasn't loaded yet. There is no way to edit elements before they've loaded.

The `<noscript>` tag can be used for this purpose. Wrapping an element to show if the user does not have Javascript enabled.

```html
<noscript>
  <div>Javascript isn't enabled</div>
</noscript>
<script>
  let jsenabled = document.createElement("div");
  jsenabled.innerText = "Javascript is enabled";
  document.body.appendChild(jsenabled);
</script>
```